# How to give support request contributor role access in Azure?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I was going via [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal). and got to know that how to give access. However, my requirment is to give contributor access to group of people (or couple of members), which will enable them to **create support ticket with Microsoft** in case there are some issues ralted to portal or in their day to day activities. How to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a support request, you must be an **Owner**, **Contributor** or be assigned to the **Support Request Contributor** role at the subscription level

To assign any of these roles, you need to login to Azure Portal

Go to subscriptions and select your subscription

Go to Access Control and click on Role Assignments and click on Add

[image]

Select Add Role Assignment and select **Support Request Contributor** role --> Click on Next --> Select user, group or service principal and add the members who needs access

Click on Next --> Click on Review and Assigns

Now the users will be able to create a support request with Microsoft